# trigger question in Oracle 18C, 'declare the content'

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I do have some problems when I try to create triggers.

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER summary_check
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON POST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF : NEW.summary != SUBSTR(content,1,11) || '...' THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'The summary rule need to be followed');
END IF;
END;`
```

This one have a compiled problem which I need declare content, then if I use post.content, it tell me that this kind of context is not allowrd? both them are VARVHAR so they are the same type. not user what I should of change here .

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER date_check
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON Likes
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
V_DATE DATE;
BEGIN 
SELECT created_on
INTO V_DATE
FROM post
WHERE post_id = post.post_id;
IF : NEW.liked_on < v_date THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'the date have to entered correctly ');
END IF;
END;`
```

And here is another one, this one has no problem with compile, but when I try to test the trigger, it always say that the exact fetch returns more than requested, not sure how to I change it?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `NEW.content`?

Comment: You have a space between : and NEW

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT created_on
INTO V_DATE
FROM post
WHERE post_id = post.post_id;
```

Is not doing what you intend.  The `post_id` also refers to `post.post_id`.  So this returns all rows in `post` where `post_id` is not `NULL`.

I think you want:

```
SELECT p.created_on
INTO V_DATE
FROM post p
WHERE :NEW.post_id = p.post_id;
```

Comment: yeah I try that way but it tells me 'ORA-00904: "NEW"."POST_ID": invalid identifier'

Comment: Thanks that do works if I am using (:NEW.post_id) instead of (NEW.post_id), thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

- For your first problem, I think you don't even need trigger if both the `columns` used in the `trigger` belongs to the same `table`.

It can be done via adding `CHECK` constraint.

```
Alter table post
Add constraint summary_check
Check (summary = SUBSTR(content,1,11) || '...');
```

- For the second problem, as mentioned by @gordon, just use `:new.post_id` instead of `post.post_id`.

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks but for the first one I have to use trigger that is a requirement